# MFMailComposer is not working in iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this piece of code for `MFMailComposer` working fine in the simulator and iPhone 4, but it crashes on [3GS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3GS). What is the reason and what is the way to resolve it?

I checked it with breakpoints. `mailPicker` is not allocated with memory.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// Set the subject of email
[mailPicker setSubject:@"Somebody got place in my sh*t list"];
NSString *emailBody = @"I just added somebody to my s**t list";

// This is not an HTML formatted email
[mailPicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

// Create NSData object as PNG image data from camera image
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self captureScreen]);

// Attach image data to the email
// 'CameraImage.png' is the file name that will be attached to the email
[mailPicker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"CameraImage"];

// Show email view 
[self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];

// Release picker

[mailPicker release];
```

Comment: Regarding your crash on the 3GS - if you can provide some more info about the crash and any error codes/logs from the console then this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at least one email account is enabled on the device, the following call should return YES:

[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]

Conversely, if all accounts are disabled/removed, it will return NO.

Comment: MInd you, it does NOT CRASH if there is NO email account present on the iPhone.  Simply, if there is NO email account present on the iPhone, it just returns NO and there is no problem.